# JavaScript parse nested string to JSON.parse()

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

am facing an issue related to Json parsing in JavaScript. I have a string like below which I need to parse inside JSON.parse()

```
let object = "{ "result": "resultValue", "content": "the content for the content key will "go" here" }"
```

Now, when am doing like JSON.parse(object) 
It throws an error Unexpected token , at some index, because of nested double quotes in content value, could you please suggest how can I parse these type of string to json , thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't have that string literal, it's a syntax error, so of course there's no way you can subsequently parse it. You need to fix this problem further upstream.

Comment: This has nothing to do with parsing json.

Comment: @jonrsharpe do we have any predefine methods or something which can standarize these kind of string ?

Comment: Not if the code itself fails due to misuse of quotes.

Comment: If you delimited the whole string with single quotes, so the code actually runs, then: how could you determine which are the quotes you need to escape and which aren't? Being preceded by `:` or followed by `,` or `}` isn't necessarily sufficient for determining those that shouldn't be escaped, as those characters may also be in the values.

Comment: There's virtually no way for a machine to fix a string once it's messed up this badly. You need to fix whatever is producing it in the first place.

Comment: Are you really getting the error in `JSON.parse()`? You should be getting the error on the `let object =` line.

Answer (score 0):

Change the quotes around the JSON to single quotes, so they don't conflict with the double quotes inside the JSON. And escape the quotes around `"go"` inside the content string.

If you create the JSON with a proper JSON encoder (e.g. `JSON.stringify()` in Javascript, `json_encode()` in PHP) you shouldn't have problems like this.

```js
let object = '{ "result": "resultValue", "content": "the content for the content key will \\"go\\" here" }'
console.log(JSON.parse(object));
```